# UI in watch like in workouts watchOS 4

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I'm looking for solution to make UI similar to workouts in watchOS 4. I tried made this on WKInterfacePicker, but I can't made these interface to look the same. I want, that my UI look like this:

[Expected look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OxDjv.jpg)

Somebody did something similar to this?

Edit: I tried use WKInterfacePicker in all styles: List, Stack and Sequence also I tried WKInterfaceTable, but table is only flat table. Neither container from WatchKit does not give me expected view.

Maybe, I must use SpriteKit to do these view?

So, my question is... Which container I should use, or maybe I should modify one of WK container? It's look like WKInterfaceTable with modification, but I think, that is impossible made UI with these control.

Comment: SO is a programming site, you normally post your attempt so far and ask for help in improving it, overcoming a problem, etc.

Comment: It's programming problem, because WatchKit is very poor and don't have a lot of containers. I tried use container from WK without success, so I asked..

Comment: Ok. Post your best attempt and you’ll have better luck getting a helpful response